# Making FrameLayout transparent

Tags: android

I want my activity to appear like a big form of dialog, something which is transparent say a quarter on all the four sides and the middle part is solid where I can place the views.
I thought using Frame Layout would be the answer by placing a frame layout inside another,but I am unable to make the first one transparent.

**My XML file:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#00000000" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="75dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="Search" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="Enter Movie Name!" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </FrameLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

Its not working. Any Ideas?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this?
http://imgur.com/dBCM9WR

Comment: Yeah, thats what I want.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I solved it by using:

```
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

I don't know why it only works programmatically.

Found this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13342157) (at the end).

Comment: this is depraceted.. use setBackground(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT)); instead

Answer (score 0):

You have to set that activity's theme like this:

`Manifest.xml`

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.ImagePreviewActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"/>
```

in `res/values/styles.xml`

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="Theme.MCChilli.NoTitle">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Also, I think this answer is just a few google clicks away but whatever...

Comment: Wouldn't this make the whole activity transparent, I just want a part to be transparent.

Comment: Isnt it what you want? 'I want my activity to appear like a big form of dialog'?!

Comment: Well a dialog is solid in middle and the we can see the backgroung on all four sides, your code is making the whole activity transparent

Comment: Ok, in that case you should try it. Ever wondered what would be a usage of totally transparent activity? Of course you have to supply contentView to ImagePreviewActivity, otherwise it will be EMPTY, not transparent everywhere.

Comment: @Mohit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android